# Dynamic sets using RB trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set, red-black-tree

let us say we have a dynamic set of S of integers and an index i, we wish to find the i-th smallest negative number in S written in increasing order, if any.
example:
S= {-5, -2, -1, 2, 5} the naswer is -1 for i=3 and is undefined for i = 4.
the objective is to choose the red-black tree as an underlying data structure and define an additional attribute that allows to solve the problem in O(lg n) time. Any guides on the algorithm should be used to solve such a question?

Comment: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap15.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's called Order Statistic Tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree).

In general, you extend your tree node with an extra attribute, the size of subtrees. For a leaf, it's 1, for an inner node, it's

```
size(left_subtree) + size(right_subtree) + 1
```

Wiki has a clear explanation and pseudocode. It works with any kind of balanced tree (RB/AVl/Treap/etc), you need to support the size of subtrees during rotation (or any tree modification).